# Identify records with multiple IDs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet which is an export from a CRM database. There are two fields, email address and ContactID which I need to run a check against.

I need to know for a given email address, if it has more than one ContactID value assigned to it.

All of the email addresses are in column A and ContactIDs are in column B.

e.g. Given the data below:

```
   A           B
email1       0001
email2       0002
email2       0002
email2       0003
email3       0004
```

I need to be able to identify that 'email2' has the ID '0002' and '0003' assigned to it, but this spreadsheet has hundreds of thousands of records so this needs to be done with a formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of quick options that come to mind....

If you can, first sort your data, but it's not necessary.  Then add a helper column C that concatenates the email address with the contactID.  Finally in column D you can use a COUNTIF formula.  You can then filter column D for anything greater than 1.

The other option is a pivot table.

See both solutions below:

[image]

Comment: These answers are much more efficient than mine and will probably be of use to more people, so have marked this as the answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have since solved this problem in the following way.

Using the CONCATENATE function, I merged the values from the two fields into a third column (C), with a comma between the two values.

After copying this column to another sheet, I used the 'Remove Duplicates' function in Excel so I am left with only unique values.

From there, I used the 'Text to Columns' function to break the data back into two parts; email and ContactID, using the comma as the delimiting value.

Then I used conditional formatting in the email column to highlight duplicate values (Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Duplicate Values) (This removes all the email addresses that have only one ContactID)

And finally, I filtered the email column to only show the highlighted values which gives me a list of all email addresses which have multiple ContactIDs.

This result can be achieved much more easily with the methods provided by 'F106dart', however.